# Chrome android browser shows only a part of the web page width

Tags: android, html, css

I have a Samsung galaxy Note 2, I use chrome browser to display a web page with a top `<div>` having a width of 1280px.
As the galaxy note 2's screen is 1280px wide, I was expecting to have the whole page to be displayed at full width at once.

But it is not the case, instead, something about 980px is being displayed : I have to unzoom to see the whole page width. And it is getting very boring because, on every page, I have to unzoom again and again.

I tried something like that into the header:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

It modified something, but it is worse : looks like to display only about 640px out of my 1280px

EDIT, here are 2 html pages to test that :

--> When I display test.html, I can see only the green color, not the red. (I have to unzoom to see both color)

```
test.html :
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <div style="background-color:red; width: 1280px">
    <div style="background-color:green; width: 980px">
    hello world
    <a href="test2.html">Go next page</a>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>

test2.html :
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div style="background-color:blue; width: 1280px">
    <div style="background-color:yellow; width: 980px">
    houston we have a problem
    <a href="test.html">Go prev page</a>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I made 2 pages because when switching from one to the other, the scale is not persistent : even if I unzoom to fit the screen on test.html, I have to unzoom again for test2.html

How can I proceed to get my 1280px at once and for all my web pages ?

Comment: can you show us more of your code and maybe a jsfiddle

Comment: What code do you want ? it is a quite heavy page, it cannot be published here...

Comment: hi!! are you familiar with [media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) and [Fluid Grids](http://alistapart.com/article/fluidgrids) maybe this help you. `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />` is one of the important part having a [Responsive Web Design](http://johnpolacek.github.io/scrolldeck.js/decks/responsive/).

Comment: @jhunlio : it does not work...

Answer (score 0):

Try setting width to 100%

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=100%, initial-scale=1" />
```

EDIT:
You could also try this:

test.html

```
<html>
<head>
<meta />
</head>
<body>
<div style="background-color:red; width: 100%">
<div style="background-color:green; width:80%">
hello world
<a href="test2.html">Go next page</a>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

test2.html

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div style="background-color:blue; width: 100%">
<div style="background-color:yellow; width: 80%">
houston we have a problem
<a href="test.html">Go prev page</a>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Percentage should take your device width automatically.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot use percentage because in the final page I have several images of different sizes : I do not want to apply some rescale percentage on each of them.

Answer (score 0):

Thought i ran into the same problem, because i had a top that was 100% width, and then i saw it on my mobile, it had cut into the centering wrapper and the content that was in that.

Solution to that for me was to set min-width on the outer part, so if you dont have any outer div, set min-width on body.